# Multiple markers at this line

Tags: java, sonar

tengo varios warnings con la siguiente leyenda:

```
**Multiple markers at this line

- Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be 
 parameterized
- Map is a raw type. References to generic type Map<K,V> should be 
 parameterized**
```

Alguien sabe como debería de declararse correctamente?

Este es mi código.

```
 static Map ordenarPorValue(Map map) {

    List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
               return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
              .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
          }
     });

    Map result = new LinkedHashMap();

    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry  entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Entiendo que tu intención es trabajar con el tipo genérico `Map`. ¿La idea es que tu código sea genérico? o más bien pretendes trabajar con un `Map` particular?

Comment: Es correcto @jachguate ,que el código sea genérico, eliminando esas leyendas que argumenté anteriormente.

Comment: Debes agregarle la diamond reference <> ya que este necesita declararse y ser tipado. Puedes ver unos ejemplos de map acá https://jarroba.com/map-en-java-con-ejemplos/. Espero te ayude.

Answer (score 0):

Tu método requiere que los valores sean comparables, por tanto podrías declararlo como lo siguiente:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> Map<?, T> ordenarPorValue(Map<?, T> map) {

    List<Entry<?, T>> list = new LinkedList<>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Entry<?, T>>() {
        public int compare(Entry<?, T> o1, Entry<?, T> o2) {
               return o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
          }
     });

    Map<Object, T> result = new LinkedHashMap<Object, T>();

    for (Iterator<Entry<?, T>> it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Entry<?, T> entry = it.next();
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sino quieres decir que tipo de objeto va a se puedes poner :

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
public void ..
```